# Solving exponential equations

Tags: calculus

I have the following exponential equation

$3^x-14 \times 3^{-x}=5$

Can anyone help to solve it?

With Thanks

Comment: I tried to take log of both sides but I get confused

Comment: But as the hint below suggests, you can probably proceed further. good luck.

Answer (score 13):

**Hint :**

$3^x=t$

You should get quadratic equation .

Comment: Yes but what about the $3^{-x}$? It becomes -t?

Comment: @user161260 it becomes $t^{-1}$

Comment: @user161260 it's ok

Comment: So I found the values of $t$: $t=7$ or $t=-2$. Then I solve the $3^{x}=7$ by taking the log of both sides and I end up with the solution $x= \frac {log 7}{log 3}$.

Comment: @user161260 notice that $t$ must be positive..

Comment: That was my question :) So I rejected the $t=-2$. But why $t$ should be positive?

Comment: @user161260 Because $3^x>0$ for all $x$

Answer (score 1):

multiplying by $3^x$ we get $(3^x)^2-5\cdot 3^x-14=0$ thus we have to solve $$z^2-5z-14=0$$ with $z=3^x$ solving this equation we get $$z_1=7$$ or $$z_2=-2$$